# Getting CSS Calc percentages to update during resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a series of panels that have CSS calc/percentage based heights and widths. The panels accurately and smoothly resize after the window size has changed.

```
    height: calc(50% - 5px);
```

However, I was wondering if there was a way to have the panels resize while the window is being resized instead of after. I don't want to use any kind of JS calculation to do this! If there is a DOM API setting or a way of manually re-firing the calc() function on resize, that is acceptable.

EDIT: I don't want to be calculating widths and heights in JS. Everything else is fine.

Does anyone know a way of doing this?

Comment: DOM can never be manipulated with HTML or CSS. You'll need javascript for that. I don't think you can achieve what you want with pure CSS. Why don't you want to use JS?

Comment: why are you posting with js tags if you need a css efect

Comment: there shouldn't be much lag using calc. Please provide demo that replicates your problem

Comment: 'I don't want to use any kind of JS __calculation__ to do this!'

Comment: If there is a __DOM API__ (Yes, javascript) setting or a way of manually re-firing the calc() function on resize, that is __acceptable__.

Comment: @charlietfl There is no lag after the resize, but the calc function isn't called until afterwards.

Comment: seems to respond in real time here  http://jsfiddle.net/fjt3ayoo/ Play with frame resizer